# sorting a 2D array in C using bubblesort

Tags: c, arrays

okay, so i'm making a program where, given a 2D array of strings, i'd sort them in alphabetical order. i tried using bubblesort on this one.

this is my code so far

```
void bubbleSort(char a[][100], int sz){
    char temp[100];
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<sz; i++){
        for(j=i+1; j <sz-1; j++){
            if(strcmp( a[i], a[j] ) >0){
                strcpy(temp, a[j]);
               strcpy(a[j], a[j-1]);
                strcpy(a[j-1], temp);
            }
        }   
    }
}

main(){
    char x[10][100] = {"to","be","or","not","to","be","that","is","the","question"};
    bubbleSort(x,10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       printf("%s\n",x[i]);

    system("pause");    
}
```

it's doesn't seem to work. this is what i'd get:

```
be
or
not
be
is
to
that
the
to
question
```

like, what happened? is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing with `i` and `j`. and then swapping between `j` and `j-1`..

```
if(strcmp( a[i], a[j] ) >0){
            strcpy(temp, a[j]);
           strcpy(a[j], a[j-1]);
            strcpy(a[j-1], temp);
        }
```

swap between `i` and `j`

```
for(i=0; i<sz; i++){
    for(j=i+1; j <sz-1; j++){
        if(strcmp( a[i], a[j] ) >0){
            strcpy(temp, a[j]);
           strcpy(a[j], a[i]);
            strcpy(a[i], temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this what the output we get upon changing what you had specified. to
be
or
not
to
be
that
is
the
question

Comment: you should get in ascending order.

Comment: how about this one. if i use a qsort function instead of bubblesort, how would i do it?

Comment: @jennymalinao: read the `qsort()` algorithm.. you can apply it then, comparing and swapping just like you are doing it here..

Comment: @jennymalinao: ask another question... :)